# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' Fetch only rows which meet two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df where I need to select the rows only where the Condition1 column has value 11 and Score is positive

```
Condition1   Score
11            100
12            100            
11            -2  
11            200
11             11
11            -300
10             200

 Expected output

Condition1   Score
11            100
11            200
11             11
```

Code:

```
 df.loc[df.Condition1.eq(11) & (np.sign(df.score) >= 0)]
```

Error obtained

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I cehecked the dtype of Score and Condition1 . Condition1 is int and score is object, can that be the problem?

Comment: `df[df.Condition1.eq(11)&df.Score.gt(0)]`

Comment: I just checked, my score dtype is object dont know why....is that the problem?

Comment: Yap, `df.Score.astype(int).gt(0)`

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.7'`

Comment: Dont see why it should not work. What version are you on. Converted `Score` to `str` and this worked for me `df[df.Condition1.eq(11)&df.Score.astype(int).gt(0)]`

Comment: I am using SAP output. Let me see if there are some spaces in int etc. Dont know the exact issue

Comment: Try stripping the white spaces using ```df['column'].str.strip()``` and then try the above solution

Comment: works. thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your *df* contains in *Score* column a **text** representation of numbers,
something like you created it running:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Condition1': [11, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10],
    'Score': ['100', '100  ', '-2 ', '200', ' 11', '-300', ' 200']})
```

Note that:

- the second element contains trailing spaces,
- the 6-th and 8-th element contain a leading space.

When you run `df.info()` the result is something like:

```
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   Condition1  7 non-null      int64 
 1   Score       7 non-null      object
```

but what you see on the screen only **looks like** numbers.

And this is just the reason why plain *astype(int)* fails:
The above strings (with either leading or trailing spaces) are **not**
convertible to *int*.

To cope with your problem:

- first drop these spaces,
- then convert this column to *int*.

The code to do it is:

```
df.Score = df.Score.str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)
```

Now when you run `df.info()` the result should be something like:

```
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------      --------------  -----
 0   Condition1  7 non-null      int64
 1   Score       7 non-null      int32
```

And now, as *Score* column is a number, when you run:

```
df.loc[df.Condition1.eq(11) & (np.sign(df.Score) >= 0)]
```

you should get the expected result.

Note: Your column is named *Score* (with **upper case** "S"), but in your
code sample you wrote *score* (with **lower case** "s"). Remember to correct
this detail.

## Edit

You can simplify your instruction, changing it to:

```
df.loc[df.Condition1.eq(11) & (df.Score >= 0)]
```